# Folders getting corrupted on SD card after installing something?

Tags: windows-8, sd-card

I got a cheap 64GB card from eBay for like $10 for my Venue 8 Pro Windows 8 tablet, and after installing something to a folder or copying large files to any folder, that folder just gets corrupted.

I've permanently mounted it to a folder on my C drive, and say after downloading a torrent to the Downloads folder (on it) or downloading a game from Steam (where Steam is installed on the SD card), the Steamapps folder just gets corrupted. I can't delete these corrupted folders.

I've analyzed that it happens after a lot of writes to the SD card and the only way to fix it is to format the card. The FS is NTFS. Is this happening because this is a cheap SD card, or is there any other reason?

Screenshot of the error while browsing the folder:
[image: Error]

Here's the title of the SD card on eBay if it gives any info:

```
New 64GB Micro SD Card + Adapter MicroSD Class 10 TF Flash Memory SDHC - USA
```

Comment: first guess would be that it's not a real 64GB, so it just writes over itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin the seller has a pretty high feedback and has sold 600+ of these according to Ebay, http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-64GB-Micro-SD-Card-Adapter-MicroSD-Class-10-TF-Flash-Memory-SDHC-USA-/221691152810

Comment: It's either not real, or has a bad controller or bad sectors. If it's new enough, send it back, see if the next one's any better. General rule -  SDs are just too flaky to be messing with once they start to fail. Recover what data you need/can, then throw it away. If you have another, test it by writing a full 64GB to it & see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it sounds like the card isn't real. Some people format the card to appear larger than it actually is. I've fallen for this trick myself a few years ago. $10 for a 64GB card is unrealistic.

I'd recommend seeking a refund through PayPal protection insurance.

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-64GB-Micro-SD-Card-Adapter-MicroSD-Class-10-TF-Flash-Memory-SDHC-USA-/221691152810 that's the link to it, are you sure it might be fake?

Comment: Yep, now i've seen that i'm certain. Thats the exact same packaging mine came in.